# omxplayer works but fbdevsink doesn't -- any ideas?

Tags: video, omxplayer, gstreamer

I'm trying to output video content on the Pi without X11.  I'd like to use `tvservice` to set the resolution settings then be able to run pipelines like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! fbdevsink`

I see that /dev/fb0 exists, and I can write to it without errors, e.g.:

```
cat `which bash` > /dev/fb0
```

But I just end up with a blank screen.  My gpu_mem in config.txt is set to 128meg.  If it matters my current `tvservice` is:

```
state 0x120006 [DVI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this issue had to do with having called tvservice to change the screen resolution.  Apparently after this is done a corresponding call needs to be made to fbset.

So for example if I go to DMT mode 16 (1920x1080):

`tvservice -e "DMT 16`

I need to follow that up with:

`fbset -g 1920 1080 1920 1080 16`

Now `fbdevsink` works.  `omxplayer` seems to work regardless because it somehow goes around the frame buffer.